# When I try to change colour depends on the count it show's the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In the below I would like to change the colour to black if the count is === 0

```
if(Count === 0){
    document.getElementById('value').style.color = 'black';
}
return(
    <div className='container_new'>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <span id='value'>{Count}</span>
        <div>
            <button className="btn decrease"  onClick={handleDecrement} >decrease</button>
            <button className="btn reset" style={{color: 'black'}} onClick={() => handleReset()}>reset</button>
            <button className="btn increase" onClick={() => handleIncrement()}>increase</button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Why mix React with directly interfering with the DOM? Why don't you do e.g. `<span style={{ color: Count === 0 ? 'black' : 'green'>{Count}</span>` or conditionally set a class instead?

Comment: Inline style worked as i wanted....Thank you jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you wanted this way.

```
return(
    <div className='container_new'>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <span id='value' style={{ color: Count === 0 ? 'black' : 'white' }}>{Count}</span>
        <div>
            <button className="btn decrease"  onClick={handleDecrement} >decrease</button>
            <button className="btn reset" style={{color: 'black'}} onClick={() => handleReset()}>reset</button>
            <button className="btn increase" onClick={() => handleIncrement()}>increase</button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in react.js i would approach this differently  because it render and change the DOM (html tree)

so maybe instead of using

```
**document.getElementById('value').style.color = 'black';**
```

make a class in CSS and change the className based on the Count

like this

### css class

```
    .black {
    color : black;
       }

.green {
color : green;
}
```

### react.js code

```
  <span id='value' className={Count === 0 ? "black" : "green"  }  >{Count}</span> // tell me if this line is understandable
```

replace this line with your line and see if is working !

it would help me understand better if you show us the the handle increment function handle reset and handle decrement :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your react state is `state = { Count: 0 }`, If yes, when react starts initial rendering, you're trying to get the element by id, at this time, there no element(not rendered) with `<span id='value'>{Count}</span>` which returns null. That's why you're getting this error `Cannot read property 'style' of null`.

But, you can simply use following solution

```
<span id="value" style={{ color: Count === 0 ? 'black' : 'green' }}>{Count}</span>
```

Comment: Agree, nicely explained!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a local state for the **count** and track the update. Based on the count value in the state, update the template style.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

return(
    <div className='container_new'>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <span id='value'>{count}</span>
        <div>
            <button className="btn decrease"  onClick={handleDecrement} >decrease</button>
            <button className="btn reset" style={{color: (count === 0 ? 'black': 'green')}} 
                        onClick={() => setCount(0)}>reset</button>
            <button className="btn increase" onClick={() => handleIncrement()}>increase</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```